# Lotus Notes-> How to export/extract whole code of all agents in application to text file or other file?

Tags: lotus

Is it possible to export/extract whole code of all agents in application to text file or other file? Users report a lot of incidents with error popups. In these popups can be find specific error messages. In C++ code or other there is a possibility to find the place in the code with the specific error message using a primitive way: searching the file content with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
Is It possible to achieve the same in Lotus Notes applications? In Lotus Notes Designer (LN 6.5) I don't see such option. I can only search in a specific agent code in such a way and not through all agents.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Design Synopsis (in designer, right click on the database->Application->Design Synopsis.  You can select the design elements you want to see.  That will create a document that you can search through or copy/paste to your favorite editor to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Download a Domino R9 Designer, then you can search the design.
Or use DDSearch, download from http://domquery.info/samples/sandbox.nsf/ByProduct/f090b24ea76b1c0100256c45003e6396?OpenDocument